# Get all gmail threads with google script

Tags: scripting, gmail

In Google scripts I can get inbox threads by

```
GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,100);
```

but how can I get all threads, last 100, not just in the inbox. Or better yet all threads created yesterday.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

How about this answer? I think that you can achieve what you want to do using Gmail API. When you use these sample scripts, please enable Gmail API at Advanced Google Services and API console.

### Preparation for using sample scripts

#### Enable Gmail API v1 at Advanced Google Services

- On script editor

  - Resources -> Advanced Google Services
  - Turn on Gmail API v1

#### [Enable Gmail API at API console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/gmail.googleapis.com/overview)

- On script editor

  - Resources -> Cloud Platform project
  - View API console
  - At Getting started, click Enable APIs and get credentials like keys.
  - At left side, click Library.
  - At Search for APIs & services, input "Gmail". And click Gmail API.
  - Click Enable button.
  - If API has already been enabled, please don't turn off.

If now you are opening the script editor with the script for using Gmail API, you can enable Gmail API for the project by accessing this URL https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/gmail.googleapis.com/overview

### Sample scripts

#### 1. Retrieve 100 threads

```
var result = Gmail.Users.Threads.list("me", {maxResults:100});
```

#### 2. Retrieve all threads created before 1 day.

```
var result = Gmail.Users.Threads.list("me", {q: "newer_than:1d"});
```

### References :

- [Advanced Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)
- [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/)
- [Search operators you can use with Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en)

If this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.